# When i try to apply "Font" to one tableview cell it automatically apply to other cells when scroll tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, fonts, uifont, custom-cell

I have a custom tableview.

I need to set Bold Italic (Helvetica-BoldOblique) font to only cell.But when it scroll the tableview it also apply to other cells one by one.How to solve this?

```
    func applyFontToTableviewCell() {

    var couIn = NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0)
    var couCell = colorTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(couIn)
    couCell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-BoldOblique", size: 18.0)


    }
```

I tried this same code in  cellForRowAtIndexPath also.But the same issue occured.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if (NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)==1){ couCell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-BoldOblique", size: 18.0)} else{//use the normal font  }

Comment: s i know what is the issue...

Comment: Only one row you need to bold rest will be normal , am i right ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply can you explain whats the issue

Comment: Not only one row may be it extend to one or two rows but not all rows.

Comment: can you explain little bit more at which condition basis you need...?

Comment: Ok i will update my question

Comment: Replace this with couCell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-BoldOblique", size: 18.0) @ashish code

Comment: If the cell is 2,4,6 means i need the textlabel to bold.Other cells to normal.

Comment: if (NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0) || (NSIndexPath(forRow: 4, inSection: 0) || (NSIndexPath(forRow: 6, inSection: 0)){
      couCell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-BoldOblique", size: 18.0)
  }
  else{
      //set your default font
  }     try like this only static value. For dynamic values follow modulo and i moving for break catch u later

Comment: i told u this one only

Comment: yes :) that why i give you the up vote in comment for ashish also

Comment: is there any way to display array of fonts to the tableview cell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82170/discussion-between-lyida-and-spynet).

Comment: I think you are reusing the cell for the scrolled cells: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106373/uitableviewcell-reuse-good-practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can applied bold font on alternative cell like as bellowed way.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let couCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

            let row = indexPath.row

            if row == 2 || row == 4 || row == 6 {
              couCell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-BoldOblique", size: 18.0)
           }
          else{
               couCell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18.0)
           }

            return cell
        }
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: @Lyida, what issue, have you faced?

Comment: means, you need bold text on only 2,4,6 cell? other all are in normal font. right?

Comment: yes.But when scroll the tableview all cell text are bold

Comment: @Lyida, i have updated code as per your requirement. kindly replace it. it was working fine at my end.

Comment: thanks and what about   couCell? or you replace it with cell

Comment: @Lyida, used just 
            if row == 2 || row == 4 || row == 6 {
              couCell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-BoldOblique", size: 18.0)
           }
          else{
               couCell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18.0)
           }  code only. other things keep yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82177/discussion-between-lyida-and-none).

Answer (score 2):

You have to check by if conditions :

```
if (NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0)){
      couCell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-BoldOblique", size: 18.0)
}
else{
      //set your default font
      couCell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18.0)
}
```

if you want to check odd and even then

```
if yourindexpath % 2 == 0 {
}
```

so, may be it would be like

```
if (NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row % 2, inSection: 0)){
  couCell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-BoldOblique", size: 18.0)
}
else{
  //set your default font
  couCell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18.0)
}
```

Comment: Ok how to i determine the the cell "var couCell = colorTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath()"'.I need to find the second cell too

Comment: But it apply to other cells when i scroll tableview.In so many ways i tried.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and fixed by applying font in `willDisplayCell` method

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell:  UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let row = indexPath.row

        if row == 2 || row == 4 || row == 6 {
          cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-BoldOblique", size: 18.0)
       }
      else{
           cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18.0)
       }
    }
```