# tableview cells mix after scrolling (swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, reuseidentifier

I made a table view that fills the cells with some data, which works fine.

The problem is that, when I scroll the table, all the cells get mixed, do you know a way to stop this?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let celda = tabla_reportes.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("celda", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! celdaReportes
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        celda.datos = tipos
        celda.back = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    case 1:
        celda.index = indexPath.row
        celda.datos = fillArrayWithData(datos[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary)
        celda.back = UIColor.clearColor()
    default:
        break
    }
    celda.delegate = self
    return celda
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should update field of the cell. maybe  you here  [UITableViewCell reuse good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106373/uitableviewcell-reuse-good-practic)  can help you

Answer (score 0):

Because the cells are reused for performance. Eg, when you scroll up the tableview and the number 1 cell disappears, the number 10 cell is actually your number 1 cell. Whatever you set in number 1 cell and the value is not updated stays with number 10 cell and so on...Try put a blank value inside your cell if it has no value.